# How to autoscale the tikzpicture linewidth when I zoom out the doc?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scale

I am drawing a semicircle that I am going to subscript an A to represent the area of that semicircle and when I do it I notice that when compiling, when I look at the page without zooming, the figure of the semicircle looks thicker.

How can I make the semicircle look like the triangle or square when I zoom out the page?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{relLineWidth/.style={line width=##1pt, line width relative}}
        \draw [line width= 0.15pt](0,0) arc (0:180:0.125) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \newcommand{\semicirc}{\begin{tikzpicture}[transform shape]
        \draw [line width= 0.3pt](0,0) arc (0:180:0.125) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}}

    El área vendrá dada por:
    \begin{equation*}
        A = 2 \cdot A_{\vartriangle} + A_{\square} + A_{\semicirc}
    \end{equation*}
```

[image: Different line width]

Thanks!

Comment: One way would be to draw the triangle and square in TikZ as well. However, since it is viewer- and zoom level-dependent, it may not help much - maybe the new version will be uneven on another zoom level, or this one is even for another person that looks at the pdf in a different viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about tikz line widths, you could instead use one of the semicircles form the `wasysym` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

    El área vendrá dada por:
    \begin{equation*}
        A_{\rotatebox{90}{\Rightcircle}}
    \end{equation*}

\end{document}
```